# Angular.JS - Looking for some insight on defining simple properties on the model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, durandal

I'm slowly working through some of the demos on the angular.js site.  One of the things I noticed was that it seems we don't have to define a model/properties like I would in a durandal project for example.

To be clearer, how can we "use" the property "yourName" from this example without actually declaring it somewhere? (it seems we haven't even defined a model at all in this case) [tutorial 1](https://angularjs.org/#the-basics)

In another example, we create a model that doesn't define "todoText" yet we are somehow able to use it? [tutorial 2](https://angularjs.org/#add-some-control)

Perhaps I'm just not clear on some of the finer points of angular yet.  Feel free to point me in the right direction if I'm making any wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept behind both tutorials is the same one.

Take the first one as an example. The property `yourName` is defined as the input's model (`ng-model="yourName"`). This is automagically binded to the controller behind it and used later to display the written name with `{{yourName}}`.

Should you have a controller behind this, you can access `yourName` through `$scope.yourName` and, if you define it before hand and assign a value to it, the input will have that value by default.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think it was the "automagically" part that scared me.  In practice, I imagine we will define controllers and defaults explicitly for almost everything but the simplest of apps.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model="yourName"` is the same as writing `$scope.yourName=""` in your controller.

Here is an example that might shed some light.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="scopedInHtml" placeholder="Enter Stuff Here"/>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('scopedInHtml', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal);
  });
});
```

Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WeJP0IWopUUrYVEuxDTC?p=preview